# PDF library which support conversion of heavy html into pdf

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

Currently I am using **DOMPDF**. and it works well.

but when i try to convert heavy html with images into pdf, there dompdf fails. it uses a lot of resources and produce a heavy pdf(4.5 MB). another issues I face with DOMPDF tht it produces some random images on pdf in place of original images.

Then i try online conversion on this site http://htmlpdf.com/

It convert that html with in seconds and produce 279kb pdf. and it also do image optimization by itself.

but I am still looking for PDF library which support conversion of heavy html into pdf and also support horizontally big html into pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Google provides better one. wkhtmltopdf library

Comment: But its library is not in PHP. It provide EXE file.